# xp_cmdshell como colocar pastas que tenham espaço?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec

Coloquei uma pasta no terminal

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir b:\teste\*xlsx*'
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir b:\teste teste\*xlsx*'
```

Quando adiciono o espaço ele não encontra. Fica inviavel mudar o nome de todas as pastas que tenham espaço pq tem várias para encontrar o caminho até onde eu quero todos os arquivos, como posso fazer para ele identificar essas pastas que contem o caracter de espaço sem dar erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar **aspas duplas** no inicio e no fim do caminho:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir "b:\teste teste\"'
```